# Do multiple IIS worker processes recycle at the same time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

If there are 2 or more worker processes in a single application pool, do they all recycle at the same time based on the default value of 1740 minutes?

The reason for this question is that we are generating a key on the server that will be based in part on the current DateTime (dd mm YYYY) value so all Worker Processes needs to hold the same value in their own session cache.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using multi-process application pools then you shouldn't use the in-proc session state service because there's no guarantee that requests from the same client will always be routed to the same worker-process - so there would be issues with keeping session-state.

Comment: That said, what you mention sounds more like a static-state issue. There are ways you can ensure multiple nodes in a distributed system hold the same value. Are you using any kind of IPC?

Comment: @Dai for simplicity lets assume that the session cache value is DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyy") - Note that i'm not using minutes or second values as i'm concerned if the different instances are recycling out of unison around midnight.